# Tags and element got printed when tried to get only text with web scraping in beatutifulsoap in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently learning web scraping and I came across a problem in beautiful soap module. 
I ran the following code:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.weather.gov/')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
comicElem = soup.find('#topnews p')
print (len(comicElem))
```

And when I am running it shows the result but also shows the tags and in which
element it is. Like:

[image: Result]

How can I hide the **paragraph** tag? Is there any different way? Please check your solution and answer.

> **Facts** : I use python 3.5, windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the inner text of an element:

```
comicElem.get_text()
```

Note that if there are multiple elements, you would need to call `get_text()` for every element:

```
[elm.get_text() for elm in soup.find_all('#topnews p')]
```